# jQuery Validation plugin rules to specific form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm using the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate my forms. Now I want to validate each form on my site. This works:

```
$('form').validate({
    <?php echo $translation["validation_lang"];?>
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
        $(element).tooltipster('show');
    },
    success: function (label, element) {
        $(element).tooltipster('hide');
    }
});
```

I'm using [Tooltipster](http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/) to show the errors next to their corresponding field. Again, **this works**. The `PHP`-string in there is to optionally load a language pack.

Now I have other forms on my site that require additional rules. For example, the register form should check username availability, check username validity (length, characters, ...), etc.

```
$('#registerForm').validate({
    rules: {
        username: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 50
        },
        password1:  {
            minlength: 5
        },
        password2:  {
            minlength: 5,
            equalTo: "#password1"
        },
        email: {
            remote:{
                url: "getContent.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    type: "checkMail"
                }
            }
        },
        username:   {
            remote: {
                url: "getContent.php",
                type: "post",
                data:   {
                    type: "checkUser"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages:   {
        email:  {
            remote: "<?php echo $translation["already_registered"][0];?>"
        },
        username:   {
            remote: "<?php echo $translation["already_registered"][1];?>"
        }
    }
});
```

Having these two snippets of code on the same page does not work. When having the body of the code above (thus the `rules` and `messages`) inside the initial `$('form').validate({` instead of it's own `$('#registerForm').validate({` it does work. I can't seem to find anywhere how to add certain rules to specific form's, whilst maintaining the 'general' rules for all forms.

**So in short:** How do I add rules/messages/submitHandlers to specific forms with a certain ID, whilst maintaining the general form-rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the setDefaults method to define common validation stuff:
http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.setDefaults/

Example:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
    $(element).tooltipster('show');
},
    success: function (label, element) {
    $(element).tooltipster('hide');
}
});
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ngdq/) - Setting error element to "em" for all forms.

Comment: I still need all the forms to be validated, but apparantly I can do this by placing the `$('form').validate();` after the specific validations, whilst setting the defaults before any validation. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to iterate through your forms with [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/):
`$("form").each(function() {
            $(this).validate();
});`